# Ignoring parameters in C functions

Tags: c

I'm integrating a C library into an Objective-C app for iOS.  I'm not very C-savvy... I know just enough to be dangerous.

The C function declaration is this:

```
extern int ZEXPORT unzGetCurrentFileInfo OF((unzFile file,
                         unz_file_info *pfile_info,
                         char *szFileName,
                         uLong fileNameBufferSize,
                         void *extraField,
                         uLong extraFieldBufferSize,
                         char *szComment,
                         uLong commentBufferSize));
```

I am really only interested in the `szFileName`.  I know I can ignore the `void*` and `char*` by passing `NULL`.  Can I pass some sort of `NULL`-equivalent to the `uLong` params?  I'm getting a compiler warning about converting to pointer without a cast.

Here's my loop for calling this function, in case anyone wants to comment on that.  Did I do the `malloc`/`free` correctly?  I'm not used to the low-level C stuff.  I know people complain about Objective-C reference counting but in comparison it's pretty luxurious :)

```
unz_file_info pfile_info;
char *szFileName = malloc(1024);
uLong fileNameBufferSize;
uLong commentBufferSize;
uLong extraFieldBufferSize;

do {
    int ret = unzGetCurrentFileInfo(zipFile, &pfile_info, szFileName, fileNameBufferSize, NULL, extraFieldBufferSize, NULL, commentBufferSize);
    NSLog(@"get info ret %i filename size %lu, filename %s", ret, pfile_info.size_filename, szFileName);
    // do other stuff here with the filename
}
while (unzGoToNextFile(zipFile) == UNZ_OK);
free(szFileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ulong parameters are the sizes of the buffer arguments. This is so the function knows how big those buffers are so it doesn't overflow them.

If you need the fileName argument, you  must supply a correct fileNameBufferSize.

As for whether you actually can pass in a NULL pointer to the pointer arguments, only the documentation(or source code) for this function can tell you. Or if the documentation doesn't tell you, you'll have to do some basic science experiments on the function and see how it behaves.

Assuming the function accepts NULL pointers for parameters you don't want filled in, you'd likely pass 0 as the value for the ulong parameters.

You'll have to do:

```
unz_file_info pfile_info;
char *szFileName = malloc(1024);
uLong fileNameBufferSize = 1024;
if( szFileName == NULL) {
  //handle error
  return;
}

do {
    int ret = unzGetCurrentFileInfo(zipFile, &pfile_info, szFileName, fileNameBufferSize, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
    NSLog(@"get info ret %i filename size %lu, filename %s", ret, pfile_info.size_filename, szFileName);
    // do other stuff here with the filename
}
while (unzGoToNextFile(zipFile) == UNZ_OK);
free(szFileName);
```

You should also investigate the meaning of the return value of unzGetCurrentFileInfo. If it fails, it's unlikely you can use `szFileName` or any of the other arguments to the function - so don't call NSLog with those variables if the function fails

In this case, malloc seems unneccesary. Just use a local array, and drop the free() call.

```
char szFileName[1024];
uLong fileNameBufferSize = sizeof szFileName;
```

Comment: oh, excellent... i misunderstood what the fileNameBufferLength stuff was, I thought it was going to be filled in with the length of the filename, I didn't realize I was telling the function how big of a buffer I allocated!  (It seems weird to me because what if I allocate a too-small buffer?  I guess the function it would just truncate the result, but that seems like a silly thing to do.)

Comment: Truncating the result may seem like a silly thing to do, but the function has no choice. If it wants to write 100 bytes but you've  given it a buffer that's only 80 bytes, it __can't__ write the extra 20 bytes or it will be overwriting memory with potentially disastrous results. There's nothing it can do _except_ truncate the string.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I pass some sort of `NULL`-equivalent to the uLong params? I'm getting a compiler warning about converting to pointer without a cast.

Not in general; the permitted values for parameters should be listed in the manual of the library you're embedding (zlib, by the likes of it). Don't pass `NULL` to a function that expects a `long`, that's invalid.

Worse: you are passing the values of **uninitialized variables** `fileNameBufferSize`, `extraFieldBufferSize` and `commentBufferSize` to the function. Your program has undefined behavior. Set these variables appropriately, or use literals/expressions for the arguments.

> Did I do the `malloc`/`free` correctly?

You forgot to check the return value from `malloc`. Always check for NULL. Even better: since you're allocating a constant amount of memory, just do so on the stack:

```
char szFileName[1024];
```

No need for `malloc` or `free`. <s>(And you might want to use `PATH_MAX` instead of the arbitrary 1024. What if pathnames may be longer than that on your platform?)</s>

**Edit**: never mind about the `PATH_MAX` part; the max. length of this string should be documented in the zlib docs, since it's not the max. length of a part on your system but the max. length zlib is willing to store.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I pass some sort of NULL-equivalent to the uLong params?

There isn't a globally-accepted NULL for non-pointer parameters; it depends on the function. In some cases, you can pass in 0, but not always.

In this case, you're passing in the size of a buffer and supplying NULL for the buffer, so it would seem logical that passing 0 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I pass some sort of
>   NULL-equivalent to the uLong params?

How about `0`?

> Did I do the `malloc`/`free` correctly?

Looks ok to me.

You have some other error though: `fileNameBufferSize` is supposed to be the size of the `szFileName` buffer (1024 in your code). You didn't fill it, which means it's trash, be careful with that.

**edit**

Yep, you should check the `malloc` returned value for NULL, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along these lines here. I removed the unused vars and instead of a malloc/free a simple allocation in the stack will do.

```
#define FNAME_SZ 1024 //should really read the docs on your target platform to find the proper size
unz_file_info pfile_info;
char szFileName[FNAME_SZ];

//initialize. important just to be sure
memset(szFileName, 0, FNAME_SZ);

do {
    int ret = unzGetCurrentFileInfo(zipFile, &pfile_info, szFileName, FNAME_SZ, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
    NSLog(@"get info ret %i filename size %lu, filename %s", ret, pfile_info.size_filename, szFileName);
    // do other stuff here with the filename
}
while (unzGoToNextFile(zipFile) == UNZ_OK);
```